# Number of Components of Pretzel links

Tags: combinatorics, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

I am interested in the number of components (denoted by $N$) of the [Pretzel Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretzel_link) $(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$. I understand the following facts about this:

1. Each $p_i$ can be considered as $0$ or $1$, depends on the parity of $p_i$;
2. When $n$ and $p_i$'s are all odd, or when exactly one $p_i$ is even, $N=1$;
3. When $n$ is even and $p_i$'s are all odd, $N=2$.

**Question: Is there a general formula for computing $N$ as a function of $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ and $n$?**

By the way, though this question is from topology, I feel it more like a combinatoric question and thus have tagged it accordingly.

Comment: On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretzel_link) there is a sufficient and necessary condition for a pretzel link to be a knot, i.e. $N=1$. You could generalise this condition for having $N$ components.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen, I am aware of this condition on Wikipedia; however, I am wondering if there is a simple generalization to the case of $N$ components.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**: When all $p_i$'s are odd, $N=\dfrac{3-(-1)^n}{2}$; when at least two $p_i$'s are even, $N$ equals to the number of even $p_i$'s.

This generalises the condition from Wikipedia about when a Pretzel link is a knot.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to provide a proof and to update the article on wikipedia. I was asking myself the same question today.